# Why is this.props.navigator.push throwing an error?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, navigator-ios

I am building a React-native app for iOS (I am fairly new to this framework).

I have a button and once you click it, it should take you to the login view, Once the user clicks the button, it should navigate the user to the LoginPage Component. But currently when I do that I get the error you see in image.

[image]

```
 'use strict'

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image, 
  Button,
  ActivityIndicator,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';


import LoginPage from './login';

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {



  myPress = () =>{
    //This is where the error occurs
    this.props.navigator.push({
      title: 'log in to YourHope.io',
      component: login,
      passProps: null,
  });
  }

  render() {
    let pic = {
      uri: 'https://example.com'
    };
    let logo = {
      uri: 'https://example.com'
    }
    const companyName = 'Example LLC';
    const message = 'cool welcome';

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#eee', }} >
       ...

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.loginScreenButton}
          onPress={this.myPress}
          underlayColor='#fff'>
          <Text style={styles.loginText}>login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the login view:

```
'use strict';

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  FlatList,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';


export default class LoginPage extends Component<{}> {
    render() {
      return (
        <Text></Text>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: You need to use [Navigator](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html#navigatorios) and pass the scenes to it in order to access its props

Comment: I do not need to access props or pass any parameters, all i want it to do is change the view to the login view.

Comment: also, is `login` defined anywhere? looks like that will also crash it

Comment: Yeah, looks you are trying to set the component to LoginPage, not login.

Comment: @azium I have made those adjustments to the component and updated it to LoginPage, however I am still getting the error.

Comment: Like @PritishVaidya said.. are you even using Navigator?

Comment: @azium, I was able to find the solution on my own. Thank you for your comments.